# C# encryption example for use with GCP KMS asymmetric-decrypt

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-kms

We're making use of GCP's KMS functionality for key management. We have a C# agent which will grab the latest public key from the keyring, encrypt some data and send it to a backend service which will use asymmetric-decrypt and the keyring/key to decrypt it.

I am having difficulty getting the C# to produce an encrypted payload which works with GCP KMS, possibly incorrect padding settings somewhere? KMS just responds with "Decryption Failed."

I've tried with both `System.Security.Cryptography` and `BouncyCastle.NetCore` but to no avail. Same error every time.

KMS key created like so:

```sh
gcloud kms keys create OUR_KEY --purpose=asymmetric-encryption --location=global --keyring=OUR_KEYRING --default-algorithm=rsa-decrypt-oaep-2048-sha256
```

I then grab the public key:

```sh
gcloud alpha kms keys versions get-public-key 1 --location=global --keyring=OUR_KEYRING --key=OUR_KEY
```

The C# looks like so:

```cs
var pemReader = new PemReader(File.OpenText(args[0]));
var keys = (RsaKeyParameters)pemReader.ReadObject();
var digest = new Sha256Digest();
var eng = new OaepEncoding(new RsaEngine(), digest, digest, null);
eng.Init(true, keys);

var plainTextBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(args[1]);
var destinationPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(args[1]), $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(args[1])}.enc{Path.GetExtension(args[1])}");

int length = plainTextBytes.Length;
int blockSize = eng.GetInputBlockSize();
var cipherTextBytes = new List<byte>();
for (int chunkPosition = 0;
     chunkPosition < length;
     chunkPosition += blockSize)
     {
         int chunkSize = Math.Min(blockSize, length - chunkPosition);
         cipherTextBytes.AddRange(eng.ProcessBlock(
             plainTextBytes, chunkPosition, chunkSize
         ));
     }

File.WriteAllBytes(destinationPath, cipherTextBytes.ToArray());
```

Then attempting to decrypt the file (which is the point it fails):

```sh
gcloud kms asymmetric-decrypt --plaintext-file=output.dec.txt --ciphertext-file=input.enc.txt --keyring=OUR_KEYRING --key=OUR_KEY --location=global --version=1
```

We're expecting to get the decrypted file, but just get the error *Decryption Failed*.

Comment: There is an open known issue with BouncyCastle's Sha256Digest. Perhaps this is the issue you are experiencing? https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/issues/161

Comment: I'd also like to point out that your decrypt command is missing a space between one of the parameters. `--key=OUR_KEY--location`

Comment: Thanks for spotting @Rhaokiel; this was a copy/paste error. The ticket does indeed appear to be related. I'll keep an eye on it and see if a patched nuget package resolves this, m thanks.